# What are the pros and cons of valves being placed in a line vs valves being placed side by side in 2V engines?

Tags: chevrolet, engine-theory, valve, camshaft

As you can see in the picture below the valves in this ferrari dino dohc 2 valves per cylinder v6 engine are placed side by side and not in a row. And as you can see here in the other picture below the valves of this pushrod 2 valves per cylinder engine are placed in line and not side by side. What are the pros and cons of both of those types of placement of the valves? [image] [image]

Comment: Any 2 valves in a cylinder head will always lay on a straight line drawn between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ferrari Example:

**Pro**

- Angle of the valves give better flow into and out of the cylinder
- Revs higher

**Con**

- More complicated
- Higher center of gravity
- Less compact
- Costs more to produce and fix

Chevrolet Example:

**Pro**

- Less complicated
- Single cam to run them all
- Cheaper to produce and fix
- More compact setup

**Con**

- Angles of valve complicates flow paths (not as straight of flow to/from chamber)
- Rev range limited

Mind you, these pros/cons have more to do with the entire valve train versus just the valve placement themselves.

Comment: But didn't the original Chrysler  V 8 hemi heads run all 16 valves off of one camshaft ? I had a couple but never took them apart.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - Yes, but what does that have to do with the two examples provided by the OP? The Hemi has the same *basic* setup as the Chevrolet V8 (both are considered an Overhead Valve [OHV] configuration). The Hemi's valves are canted to allow better flow. The OP is asking about inline valves, which the Hemi does not have.